# Bootstrap Radio White Circle Is Not In Correcly Position When Change Html Font Size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple web application with bootstrap for style. I really like bootstrap, but I have some problem with my radio button, when I change my html `font-size`.

**This is my style:**

```css
* {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
}
```

When I use the code above, my radio button will looks like this:

[image]

The white circle in the radio button is not in correcly position. But when I remove `font-size` my  radio button will looks good.

[image]

Maybe someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change bootstrap base font-size. For an example, I'm use scss, then I just need to do this in my root style.scss file.

```css
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
$font-size-base: 0.875rem; // 14px
$font-family-base: 'Roboto';
```

Now,it will working fine.